# Intuition behind a braid operator which is also a solution for Yang-Baxter equation

Tags: algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, operator-algebras

I am going through [this paper](http://www2.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/QETE.pdf%E2%80%8E), 'Quantum entanglement and topological
entanglement' by Louis H Kauffman and Samuel J Lomonaco Jr published in New Journal of Physics 4 (2002).

It started with discussing braid operators which I probably get. But on page 6, when it introduces the matrix for a braid operator I don't get the intuition behind it. It is:

\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 0  &d  &0 \\ 
0 &c  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &b
\end{pmatrix}

Why is this matrix so? The paper also suggests that it is a solution of the Yang-Baxter equation.

Comment: Your linked does not work.  Do you have another link you can post?

Comment: @N.Owad, I added the details of the paper.

Comment: The interest is that you may modelise a [quantum gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate)

Comment: @Trimok, how is that?

Comment: As it is said in the [Kauffman / Lomonaco paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205137), at the end of the page $8$, to each strain, is associated a qbit, that is a $2$ - dimensional complex vector space $V$, so the matrice 4*4 $R$ matrix you cited, may be seen as a "transfert" matrix between the states "in" and "out" of 2 qbits, very similar to the [swap gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate#Swap_gate). Of course, quantum gates are of fundamental importance, being  basic quantum circuits for quantum computing.